# Stop :after element from jumping to the next row on wrap

Tags: css, flexbox, pseudo-element

I have some beautiful CSS:

```
$itemHeight: 40px;
$arrowModifier: 8;
$pageBackgroundColor: $color-gray-50;

.processBar {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    &_item {
        display: inline-block;
        background: $color-gray-200;
        height: $itemHeight;
        position: relative;
        flex-grow: 1;

        text-align: center;
        line-height: $itemHeight;

        text-decoration: none;
        color: $color-text;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;

        &:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: $color-text;
        }

        &-default {
            &:hover {
                background: $color-light-gray;
            }
        }

        &-selected {
            background: $color-white;
        }

        &:before,
        &:after {
            display: inline-block;
            content: "";
            border-style: solid;
            position: absolute;
        }

        &:first-child {
            &:before {
                left:0;
                border: none;
            }
        }

        &:not(:first-child) {
            &:before {
                left:0;
                border-color: transparent transparent transparent $pageBackgroundColor;
                border-width: $itemHeight/2 0 $itemHeight/2 $itemHeight/$arrowModifier;
            }
        }

        &:last-child {
            &:after {
                right: 0;
                border: none;
            }
        }

        &:not(:last-child) {
            &:after {
                right:0;
                border-color: $pageBackgroundColor transparent;
                border-width: $itemHeight/2 0 $itemHeight/2 $itemHeight/$arrowModifier;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML that uses it:

```
<div class="processBar">
    <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>     
    <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>     
    <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>     
    <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>     
    <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>     
    <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>
</div>
```

Here is what it does:

[image]

But at a certain size the `:after` elements can jump down, as seen here:

[image]

I don't understand why that is happening. How can I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements on a flex container are considered flex items.

The `::before` pseudo is the first item. The `::after` pseudo is the last. So you have to think of them as siblings of the other flex items.

You can try using the `order` property to re-arrange items to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

What CSS pre-processor is this? I used every pre-compiler on CodePen and got errors from the $variables so I removed them and filled them in with whatever. Is this Stylus? Anyways, besides the variables being removed and some color changes, the only significant change is that I changed `flex-wrap:wrap` to `flex-wrap:nowrap`.

**SNIPPET**

```css
.processBar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.processBar_item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #c8c8c8;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.processBar_item:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}

.processBar_item-default:hover {
  background: #808080;
}

.processBar_item-selected {
  background: cyan;
}

.processBar_item:before,
.processBar_item:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}

.processBar_item:first-child:before {
  left: 0;
  border: none;
}

.processBar_item:not(:first-child):before {
  left: 0;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 5px;
}

.processBar_item:last-child:after {
  right: 0;
  border: none;
}

.processBar_item:not(:last-child):after {
  right: 0;
  border-color: tomato;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="processBar">
  <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>
  <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>
  <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>
  <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>
  <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>
  <a href="javascript:" class="processBar_item">Label</a>
</div>
```